# Function inside function: Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm using this function (part of a cordova plugin) in Angular2:

```
download()
{
//some download stuff

// ==> here this.percentage=50 works

//show progress of download
 this.fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
  if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
      console.log((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)); // works great
      this.setpercentage((progressEvent.loaded/progressEvent.total)*100) // doesn't work
      } else {}
  }
}

setpercentage(perc)
{
  this.percentage = perc;
}
```

But `percentage` isn't updating. It says `setpercentage()` is not a function.

I'm new to Angular, and I've read somewhere about arrow functions. So I gave it a try and changed it to:

```
this.fileTransfer.onprogress((progressEvent)=>{
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        console.log((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total));
        this.setpercentage((progressEvent.loaded/progressEvent.total)*100)
    } else {}
});
```

But that breaks the whole script. The console log isn't showing the percentage anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I tried `@echonax` suggestion, without luck:

```
download()
{
        this.setpercentage(50); <-- works

        this.fileTransfer.download(**download stuff**);

        var self = this; // store outer this in a variable
        this.fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                console.log((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)); // works great
                self.setpercentage(60); // <-- doesn't work
            } else {}
        }
}

setpercentage(perc)
{
    this.percentage = perc;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
this.fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
```

to

```
this.fileTransfer.onprogress = (progressEvent)=> {
```

Your `this` is not refering to your component

this is similar to doing

```
var self = this; // store outer this in a variable
this.fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
  if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
      console.log((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total)); // works great
      self.setpercentage(60, self) // <-- use it here
      } else {}
}

setpercentage(perc, self)
{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      self.percentage = perc;
    },0);
}
```

But with the second approach your `this` inside the `setpercentage` method will refer to the functions instance and not to the component

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. The console shows the percentage, but `setpercentage` isn't called. I've tried both approaches.

Comment: @binoculars your `download` method looks odd.. Shouldn't it be `download()` ? Can you add more detail? Are these methods inside a component? in the same level as the life-cycle hooks?

Comment: I've updated my question. `download` is indeed `download()`, typo.

Comment: @binoculars can you try it like this? I've updated my answer

Comment: tried it, still nothing... Hold on... it does work the second time I press the download button. Any idea why?

Comment: I've re-installed the app and can confirm it only works the second time I click the download button (and call `download()`), while the console is outputting the percentage the first time too.

Comment: @binoculars ok so we have progress :-) what is `fileTransfer` doing?

Comment: `fileTransfer` is part of `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/ Maybe something to note: it works the second time, but, it's only showing the percentage once, as a static number. It's not updating like it is on the console.

Comment: @binoculars ok so just to be sure what is not working here? That it's not calling `setpercentage`? How do you know it's not calling `setpercentage`?

Comment: Good point! Turns out, it is calling `setpercentage`. I've added `console.log('test')` to the function and the function is called every time the percentage updates.

Comment: @binoculars can you try surrounding it with a `setTimeout`? I'll update my answer as an example

Comment: Tried it, no luck :(

Comment: `setpercentage(perc, self)
{
    console.log(perc);
    setTimeout(()=>{
        self.percentage = perc;
    },0);
}`the console log in this function works, so it's passed correctly to the function.

Comment: @binoculars I got that but don't know why it doesn't update your view : / Is the view related to this component or is it in like a parent component? Can you add more info about that ?

Comment: Got it to work with the help of rapropos of the Ionic Forum (https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/view-not-updating-in-ionic-2/86468). I ended up using `setpercentage(perc, self) {
        self.ref.detectChanges();
        self.percentage = perc;
    }`

Comment: @binoculars ah, that was the reason why I wrapped it up with setTimeout, to trigger change detection manually. It's odd that it didn't work. Anyway glad it worked out :-) you can give your own answer and mark it as accepted if the issue is solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed out by rapropos](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/view-not-updating-in-ionic-2/86468/2), injecting a `ChangeDetectorRef` and calling its `detectChanges()` method after modifing the `percentage` property of the controller, resolves this issue!